# Users with non-authorized Twitter accounts having trouble with my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, acaccount, acaccountstore

When users upgraded to iOS 7, they had to re-authorize their Twitter accounts. Currently, I have a problem which seems to arise from when a user has multiple accounts, one or more of which is not verified.

When a user has multiple accounts, and one requires authorization, running this method will give a completion handler with YES, and a nil error:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Continuing onwards, the app will fail to access Twitter from that account, and cause a crash.

Reading the documentation shows that ACAccount **has** a `credential` property, but that `this property is inaccessible after the account is saved`, so that can't be used as an indicator.

ACAccountStore does have another method:

```
- (void)renewCredentialsForAccount:(ACAccount *)account completion:(ACAccountStoreCredentialRenewalHandler)completionHandler
```

But this forces the user to renew their credentials when it's called, not ideal if they already have.

How can I actually find out if an account requires it's credentials be renewed, or if it's accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should renew the user account just if it is out of sync. This may happen if the user has changed his password or when the account session has expired.

You can know that using the following notification:
[ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountStoreClassRef/ACAccountStore.html#//apple_ref/c/data/ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification)